# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy

Tags: json, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm using a Restful web service (Jersy implementation) with a JSF application and used Json to get the data as follows:

```
    carObjectDao = new GenericDAO<carObject>(carObject.class);
    List<carObject> allCars = carObjectDao.readAll();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String carString = gson.toJson(allCars);
    System.err.println(carString );
    return carString ;
```

i run the application in debug mode and allCars is filled with the data correctly, but after that an exception is thrown :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

i don't know the root cause of the exception

Comment: You have to unproxy the HibernateProxy objects, or if you dont really need the data, just set em as null.

Comment: could you explain more, i didn't understand

Answer (score 6):

This is a known problem: [Could not serialize object cause of HibernateProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459718/could-not-serialize-object-cause-of-hibernateproxy)

JSon can't deserialize HibernateProxy objects, so you either unproxy or remove em.

Or, you can eager fetch the lazy data.

Comment: How to Unproxy or remove them, i read that post but didn't understand

Comment: Fist you have to undestand how the lazy initialization works, when you dont eager fetch a collection, or load an object, it comes as a Hibernate proxy collection/object, you have to find out from your allCars objects, which child collection/objects are coming as HibernateProxy instead of real data.

Comment: After that, you can decide what to do with em (remove em or fix em).

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing through **ObjectMapper** as

```
    carObjectDao = new GenericDAO<carObject>(carObject.class);
    List<carObject> allCars = carObjectDao.readAll();
    String carString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(allCars);
    System.err.println(carString );
    return carString ;
```