# Spring MVC controller Json response, hibernate proxy error

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, getjson

I have a Spring controller annotated class which implements this method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/event/eventList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Event> listEvents() {
        System.out.println("############ LIST EVENTS ############");
        List<Event> events = eventService.listAllEvents();
        for(Event event : events) {
            Hibernate.getClass(event);
            System.out.println(event);
        }
        return events;
    }
```

when I call the page (localhost:8080/myapp/event/eventList) from browser, the method will be called correctly i see all the logs and the events are printed correctly meaning the event list is not empty and valid, but I get the error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

It does not return any Json representation.
I changed the method to return a string like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event/eventList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String listEvents() {

    return "{'pippo':1}";
}
```

In this case the browser show the string correctly.

did I miss something?

Comment: It tells you right there, it cannot serialize a HibernateProxy. `Hibernate.getClass` doesn't make the proxy object go magically away. You need to "unpack" it, something like `.getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation()` could do it, or just fix your architecture and don't give the controller Entities but DTOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown by com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters when GSON is trying to serialize variable 'events' to Json.

This happens, cause

```
eventService.listAllEvents()
```

returns not a list already containing all events, but hibernate proxy that will do that lazy, when the list is actually used.
GSON does not know how to serialize that proxy.

[Hibernate.getClass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getClass(java.lang.Object)) should initialize the underlying object as a side effect.

You need to call it also for the List 'events' itself, not only for every single event. The List can be a hibernate proxy also.

You may find more info on that topic at
[Could not serialize object cause of HibernateProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459718/could-not-serialize-object-cause-of-hibernateproxy)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, the solution for me was to add Annotation `@JsonIgnore` on every class variable in Event representing an external relationship.