# load method in Hibernate hitting database

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

I understand `session.load()` method in Hibernate.

```
Employee emp = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, new Long(1));
```

Above will just return proxy, not hitting the database until any method is called on `emp` object.

I read that if i call identifier i.e. `emp.getId()`, then also no database call is made. But when I ran, it did call the database even though I have below in Employee class.

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: may be this links help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434636/elegant-way-of-unproxy-hibernate-objects

Comment: getId() is also hitting database which should haven't been the case

Comment: I'm confused. What is your question again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `getId()` to not initialize the proxy, annotations must be put on getters, and not on fields.

If they're put on fields, as I understand it, Hibernate doesn't consider the getters as a way to access the persistent state of the entity (since it accesses the fields directly), but as methods that might do something other than simply returning the corresponding attribute. So the state is loaded before executing the method.